# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logLevels')

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

After updating webdriverio package `webdriverio=7.34.0` getting this

----------`error  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logLevels') at remote (node_modules\webdriverio\build\index.js:57:48)`

I'm trying to grab/set the geolocation in order to test different scenarios for different countries.

```
using webdriverio functions
browser.setGeoLocation({ latitude, longitude, accuracy });
```